# how can i classify attributes themselves instead the values

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, supervised-learning, unsupervised-learning

I have a data set and i need to classify this data set according to the attributes themselves instead the values.

**Picture** that describe the situation:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could make a meta-class, which uses the attributes of the classes as its values, and classify on that.

For example, using your two classes:

```
     MetaClass
Name    | Attributes
-------------------------------------
class 1 | temperature, humidite, vent
class 2 | nom, prenom, age
```

Or another way:

```
     MetaClass
Name    | Temperature | Humidite | Vent  |  Nom  | Prenom | Age
------------------------------------------------------------------
class 1 | True        | True     | True  | False | False  | False
class 2 | False       | False    | False | True  | True   | True
```

The details of making this meta-class would depend on your implementation of course.

Comment: thanks you very much for your answer. But I need a scientific way, for example, in data mining there is many algorithms of clustering and classification. Unfortunately, this algorithm work just in the values of attributes and not in the attributes themselves. if I understand you I do a meta-class and then I classify this it? please give me your opinion

Comment: Yes, that's what I would try. Depending on how you write it you could also include the attributes of the class as another attribute of each row rather than building a classifier on just the meta-class. Of course, this might not make sense since you're mixing class-level and value-level attributes - like I said, the details will depend on your specific implementation.

Comment: according to your proposition I thought that I should use a supervised Classification. But the question is how can I mix class level and the values-level attributes? for example, I will say that temperature (24,12,23,10) --> class1..... then humidité (23, 23,10,11) -->class1...... and the same for the other attributes. after that how can I classify the new enregistrement which contain both of these data for example (23,12,10, John, Pharel, 34) I need to add (23,12,10) to class1 and (John, Pharel, 10) to class2. please help me to do this classification using this example and thank you very much

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Are you saying you have a temperature and a name concatenated in the same data and want to classify part as class 1 and another part as class 2? I'm not sure how you would do that.. What I was trying to say was if you had Class 2 with columns (Nom, Prenom, Age) perhaps you could append pseudo-values so your data lines look like (John, Pharel, 34, Nom, Prenom, Age).

Comment: Look friend. I say that I want a classification according to a topic. I want to classify the column (temperature, humidity, vent) -->weather. (nom, prenom, age) -->person. I think that I should use a data mining technique. supervised classification or not supervised classification. I think to use a supervised classification. In this context, I should, for example, define a class like: temperature (24,12,23,10) --> class1..... then humidité (23, 23,10,11) -->class1, Nom (Aladin, Rfael, Jack, Mrck) -->class2.

Comment: now I have a new line of data (12,13,34,10, John, Fargo, 23) the result that I need is 12,13,34,10-->class1 and the other Class 2. hope that the idea is clear now.